# Pop up dialog issue in android

Tags: android

[image]
[image]
I have an issue in popup,my popup dialog is showing unstructured,i wanna like this,here i attached my android XML too.why my pop is too small.Here is my code i applied linear layout in fill parent this is an issue??

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Video Download Quality"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlack"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radiofrst"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="360dp" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radiosecond"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="480dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radiothird"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="720dp" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioforuth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1080dp" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can make some tweaks to the layout by adding margin or padding to the elements of the layout to make UI like you want.

Comment: please go through this [site](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-DialogFragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this set hight and width of your dialog programatically using `Window` like below code

```
Window window = customDialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
customDialog.show();
```

and add some  `android:layout_margin` or `padding` in LinearLayout like this

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_margin="10dp"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using an [android:layout_margin](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_margin) or [android:padding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:padding) in your parent layout. You can use something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some margin to your layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Video Download Quality"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlack"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radiofrst"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="360dp" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radiosecond"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="480dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radiothird"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="720dp" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioforuth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1080dp" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this. It will set in all screen size.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#50000000"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Video Download Quality"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiofrst"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="360dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiosecond"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="480dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiothird"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="720dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioforuth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1080dp" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
```